# Пайгейм столкновение объектов в игре

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Привел код, проблема в том что игра не видит столкновения двух объектов в чем причина не могу понять

```
 import pygame
 class avatar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, surf, x, y, step):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = surf
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.step = step
        self.pos = surf.get_rect().move(x, y)
    def _move(self, event):
        if self.pos.x  > 800:
            self.pos.x=0
        elif self.pos.x <0:
            self.pos.x=800
        elif self.pos.y > 600:
            self.pos.y=0
        elif self.pos.y <0:
            self.pos.y=600
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.pos = self.pos.move(0, -self.step)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.pos = self.pos.move(0, self.step)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.pos = self.pos.move(-self.step, 0)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.pos = self.pos.move(self.step, 0)
class soul(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x, y, surf, group):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(surf).convert_alpha()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.add(group)
    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x < 800:
            self.rect.x += 2
        elif pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(avt, souls) != None:
            done=True
        else:
            self.rect.x =0


pygame.init()
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
size=[800,600]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Приятной игры")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
devil=pygame.image.load("devil.png")

avt=avatar(devil,600,400,10)

souls = pygame.sprite.Group()
souls.add(soul(40,200, "s.png", souls), soul(40,300, "s.png",souls), 
soul(40,100, "s.png",souls))
background=pygame.image.load("wp.jpg")
done=False

while not(done):
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type==pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
    if i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            avt._move(i)
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(avt.image, avt.pos)
    souls.draw(screen)
    souls.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(avt, souls, True):
        print("boom")
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Загрузите, если не трудно, сами картинки, для более ясной картины

Answer (score 2):

Моя проблема была в том что я одновременно пытался использовать pos и rect. А функция проверки столкновений ориентируется только на rect. Я же использовал и то и другой в итоге пайтон, не понимал на что именно ему ориентироваться и не мог провести проверку столкновения. Поэтому я оставил только rect в итоге все успешно работает

```
 def __init__(self, surf, x, y, step):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = surf
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.step = step
```